# Flutter argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'num' Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I found this code in SO and when i try to use it with `lint` i get this error:

> error: The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter
> type 'num'. (argument_type_not_assignable ...)

```dart
MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  final List strengths = <double>[.05];
  ///

  strengths.forEach((strength) {

    /* GETTING ERROR FOR `strength` VARIABLE IN THIS LINE */
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength; /* <--- */
    ///
  });
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}
```

i tried to search on this site and google. but i can't found how can i resolve this problem

Comment: its working fine for me in dart pad. Anyway, try to change the <double>[0.05] to List<double> = [0.05]

Comment: @pedropimont i get `Missing selector such as '.identifier' or '[0]'.` error now

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce your error here. Everything is fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some solutions i found out `dart` isn't smart on casting variable. then when i changed:

```dart
final List strengths = <double>[0.05];
```

to

```dart
final List<double> strengths = <double>[0.05];
```

my project analyzer error resolved